# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type '*',but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type '..IEnumerable[*]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I looked at and implemented solutions on similar topics, but unfortunately they did not provide a solution for me.

Error Message:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'CMS.Models.Page', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CMS.Models.Page]'.

I'm working on a simple cms. My goal here is to make some changes to them after I have listed my pages.

I have been trying to fix the error for a while, but I could not get any results from the solutions I applied. My guess is a data communication problem about the model structure here. Below my codes:

HomeController:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var page = _dbContext.Pages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == "Home");
        return View(page);
    }


    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

AdminController:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AdminController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Pages
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Pages.ToListAsync());
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> EditPage(string title)
    {
        // SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE Title = {title}
        var page = await _context.Pages.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == title);

        if (page == null)
        {
            page = new Page();
            page.Title = title;

            _context.Pages.Add(page);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(page);
    }

    // GET: Pages/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var page = await _context.Pages
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (page == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(page);
    }

    // GET: Pages/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Pages/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Title,Content,Section")] Page page)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(page);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(page);
    }

    // GET: Pages/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var page = await _context.Pages.FindAsync(id);
        if (page == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(page);
    }

    // POST: Pages/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Title,Content,Section")] Page page)
    {
        if (id != page.ID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(page);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PageExists(page.ID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(page);
    }

    // GET: Pages/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var page = await _context.Pages
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (page == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(page);
    }

    // POST: Pages/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var page = await _context.Pages.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Pages.Remove(page);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool PageExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Pages.Any(e => e.ID == id);
    }
}
```

Page that i can't view => EditPage:

```
@model IEnumerable<piktusCMS.Models.Page>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Section)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Page Model:

```
    public class Page
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string Section { get; set; }
}
```

Database Context:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your solutions and suggestions

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You are passing a single `CMS.Models.Page` object to your `EditPage` view, whereas your view requires an `IEnumerable<CMS.Models.Page>`.

Comment: The error is pretty clear  - you are trying to pass a single item to view which expects collection. Either change a view to work with single item, or return collection from controller.

Comment: I solved, thank you guys. I took it as a list as you said from `EditPage` action. I couldn't notice `return(page)`. I updated as a `await _context.Pages.ToListAsync()`.

Comment: for thought; and in review to your last comment and changes inspired by the answer - lbracadabra - don't query the entire list if you don't need it. just do `return View(new [] {page})` if you don't want to change the `@model` in the view.  When you have reason to deviate from the provided, accept answer, you should raise that consideration and reasoning for deviating to that answer (especially if that answer disregards there being more than one means of how to resolve the exception but relates it to your scenario).   improving questions and answers is an iterative process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model in EditPage is a type of `IEnumerable<piktusCMS.Models.Page>` but you send `piktusCMS.Models.Page` type model from your EditPage action. You just need to change your model in the view page. From this `@model IEnumerable<piktusCMS.Models.Page>` to this `@model piktusCMS.Models.Page`

Comment: it's a good answer, addresses the implicit 'why' and 'how' question statements of such a question. (i.e. 'why is this exception occurring?' and 'how do I resolve it?')  But, there is more than one means of 'how' to resolve it (made clear with OP's recent comment to his question), and your answer could be improved by acknowledging that.  That is, instead of 'You just need to change...', it would be 'One way to resolve this InvalidOperationException is by changing...`.  Listing out all the possible ways to resolve this may be undesirable, but acknowledging other ways is.

Comment: yes please i need full answer